# Implications of IP Address as Subject Alt Name in certificates

Tags: certificates, ip

Are there specific known negative security implications of including the IP address of a server as a Subject Alternate Name in the server's certificate?

Comment: Server name is trivially resolvable to (public) IP, so I don't see a security issue. Functionally, though, it might not help.

Comment: Heads up, if this is going to be used on an internal server - the use of IP's is going to be deprecated. http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/transition-non-fqdn-server-names

Comment: Thanks @k1DBLITZ, I also discovered that after posting this query and was going to come back and update my post - you;ve saved me the trouble! :)